# Chat menu design

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, chat

If you go to any Stack Exchange chatroom site (e.g. Stack Exchange Chat) the top bar is different than the regular pages. This should be changed to the 'modern' design; if not possible, could you provide a specific reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chat literally hasn't changed at all from early on, and SE doesn't/hasn't had any developers working on major improvements to it in years.

So the specific reason is it's not a priority, and if there's engineering and development resources put towards chat, it'll probably be in line with the rest of the network, but there aren't.